# Property 'XXX' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to use some react components in an angular app; with some components i had success, but with this component:
PatientDetailForm

```
const PatientDetailsForm = React.forwardRef(
(
{
  details:{
    name: string,
    surname: string,
    sex: string,
    birthdate: any,
    size: string,
    height: string,
    weight: string,
    notes: string
} = {
    name: "",
    
    surname: "",
    sex: "",
    size: "",
    birthdate: new Date(),
    height: "",
    weight: "",
    notes: "",
  },
  instantValidate = false,
  onChange,
},
form
) => {
const classes = useStyles();
const [
  {
    session: { minSize, maxSize },
  },
] = useStateValue();
const nameRef = React.createRef();
const surnameRef = React.createRef();
const heightRef = React.createRef();
const weightRef = React.createRef();

const handleChange = (name) => (e) =>
  (onChange &&
    onChange({
      ...details,
      [name]: e.target.value,
    })) ||
  (name === "name" && nameRef.current.makeValid()) ||
  (name === "surname" && surnameRef.current.makeValid()) ||
  (name === "height" && heightRef.current.makeValid()) ||
  (name === "weight" && weightRef.current.makeValid());

const handleChangeDate = (value) =>
  onChange && onChange({ ...details, birthdate: value });

return (
  <ValidatorForm
    className={classes.container}
    onSubmit={() => {}}
    autoComplete="off"
    instantValidate={instantValidate}
    ref={form}
  >
    <div
      style={{
        display: "grid",
        width: "100%",
        gridTemplateColumns: "1fr 1fr 1fr",
        gridGap: "20px",
        padding: "0px 34px 0px 20px",
      }}
    >
      <TextValidator
        ref={nameRef}
        margin="dense"
        label="Name"
        className={classNames(classes.textField, classes.namesWidth)}
        value={details.name}
        onChange={handleChange("name")}
        required
        validators={["required"]}
        errorMessages={["This field is required"]}
      />
      <TextValidator
        ref={surnameRef}
        margin="dense"
        label="Surname"
        className={classNames(classes.textField, classes.namesWidth)}
        value={details.surname}
        onChange={handleChange("surname")}
        required
        validators={["required"]}
        errorMessages={["This field is required"]}
      />
      <FormControl className={classes.selectWidth}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="sex">Sex</InputLabel>
        <Select
          value={details.sex}
          inputProps={{
            name: "sex",
            id: "sex",
            classes: {
              select: classes.selectInput,
            },
          }}
          onChange={handleChange("sex")}
        >
          <MenuItem value="0">Female</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="1">Male</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
    <div
      style={{
        display: "grid",
        width: "100%",
        gridTemplateColumns: "1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr",
        gridGap: "20px",
        padding: "0px 34px 0px 20px",
      }}
    >
      <FormControl className={classes.selectWidth}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="size">Shoe Size</InputLabel>
        <Select
          value={details.size}
          inputProps={{
            name: "size",
            id: "size",
            classes: {
              select: classes.selectInput,
            },
          }}
          onChange={handleChange("size")}
        >
          {range(minSize, maxSize, 0.5).map((n) => (
            <MenuItem value={n} key={n}>
              {n}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <DatePicker
        disableFuture
        autoOk
        label="Birthdate"
        inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
        mask="__/__/____"
        value={details.birthdate}
        onChange={handleChangeDate}
        renderInput={(props) => (
          <TextField
            {...props}
            margin="dense"
            helperText=""
            className={classNames(classes.textField, classes.flexWidth)}
          />
        )}
        openTo="year"
        views={["year", "month", "date"]}
      />
      <TextValidator
        ref={heightRef}
        margin="dense"
        label="Height"
        className={classNames(classes.textField, classes.flexWidth)}
        value={details.height}
        onChange={handleChange("height")}
        validators={["isPositive"]}
        errorMessages={["Height is not valid"]}
        InputProps={{
          endAdornment: <InputAdornment position="end">cm</InputAdornment>,
        }}
      />
      <TextValidator
        ref={weightRef}
        margin="dense"
        label="Weight"
        className={classNames(classes.textField, classes.flexWidth)}
        value={details.weight}
        onChange={handleChange("weight")}
        validators={["isPositive"]}
        errorMessages={["Weight is not valid"]}
        InputProps={{
          endAdornment: <InputAdornment position="end">Kg</InputAdornment>,
        }}
      />
    </div>
    <TextField
      margin="normal"
      label="Notes"
      multiline
      rows="4"
      fullWidth
      className={classNames(classes.textField, classes.fullWidth)}
      value={details.notes}
      onChange={handleChange("notes")}
    />
  </ValidatorForm>
  );
  }
  );
```

I call it with this code:

```
 <PatientDetailsForm
          ref={patientForm}
          details={patientFormValues}
          onChange={setPatientFormValues}
        />
```

I get this error:

```
Type '{ ref: MutableRefObject<any>; details: { name: string; surname: string; sex: 
string; birthdate: any; size: string; height: string; weight: string; notes: string; 
}; onChange: Dispatch<SetStateAction<...>>; }' is not assignable to type 
'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>'.
Property 'details' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<any>
```